# Python Pandas Error trying to drop the first column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop the first column of a data frame, when I run

```
X.columns.tolist()
```

I get this:

```
['colors', 'num_critic_for_reviews', 'duration', 'director_facebook_likes', 'actor_3_facebook_likes']
```

so, I want to drop 'colors', but when I run

```
X = X.drop('colors', index=1) I get:
```

> KeyError: "['colors'] not found in axis"

I tried with the column index and also with the column label, but keep getting the same error. The funny thing is if I tried to access and use the column `colors` it works, but again if I try to drop it, get the `Not found in the axis` error.

Comment: `axis=1` not index

Answer (score 0):

To drop the column you could use

```py
X.drop(columns=['colors'])
```

If you want to explicitly remove the first one, just replace it inside the array:

```py
X.drop(columns=[X.columns[0]])
```

Comment: Thanks, the option X.drop(columns=[X.columns[0]]) doesn't produce the error, but still the variable isn't eliminated. I also tryed X = X.drop('colors', axis=1), X = X.select_dtypes(exclude=["object"]).reset_index() (this last one, drop all the object columns, but not the first one 'colors'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `axis=1` keyword instead of `index=1`

Check out the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it works if previously I reset the index of X and then use X.drop.